# Android Studio: Installing the APP on the smartphone

Tags: android, installation, smartphone

i got a little problem with installing my app on my smartphone. Its works normal when i am using the standart icon, but after changing the icon, Android studio starts the app on my smartphone normally, but i cant find the app in the app list.

What i am trying to say is that, I cant manually start the App, because its not showing on my Smartphone. Starting throuch Android studio works perfectly fine. I assume its because of my new icon, because the other work fine. I changed the Logo in the different Sizes and just exchanged the old icon with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a snapshot  of your code(xml,java and manifest), without which the forum is unable to help you.

You'll have to first update your icon in the drawable folder only then will you be able to use it in your app.